# fatal: 'abc' does not appear to be a git repository could not read from remote

Tags: git, shell

I have the below shell script named as `abc.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ -z $1 ]; then
        echo "Missing first argument (git repository path)"
        exit 1
fi
arg=$1
CHECKOUT_DIR=$(pwd)/$arg
BASE_DIR=$(pwd)
set -euo pipefail
basename=${1##*/}

if [[ $# -lt 1 ]]; then
    printf '%s: Clone the latest tag on remote.\n' "$basename" >&2
    printf 'Usage: %s [other args] <remote>\n' "$basename" >&2
    exit 1
fi
remote=${*: -1} # Get last argument
echo BASE_DIR: $(pwd)
echo $CHECKOUT_DIR
if [ "$arg" == "abc" ]; then
        echo $arg >> ${arg}.txt
        GITREPO=git@xyz.com:Foo/"$arg".git
        # previousABCReleaseTag=$(git ls-remote --tags $GITREPO |grep "\."|grep -v -|grep -v {| sort -n -t. -k3 -k4)
        previousABCReleaseTag=$(git ls-remote --tags --exit-code --refs $remote \
  | sed -E 's/^[[:xdigit:]]+[[:space:]]+refs\/tags\/(.+)/\1/g' | tail -n1)
echo "YYYYYYYYYYYY:"$previousABCReleaseTag
else
        GITREPO=git@xyz.com:Bar/"$arg".git
       # recentTag=$(git ls-remote --tags $GITREPO |grep "\."|grep -v -|grep -v {| sort -n -t. -k3 -k4)
       recentTag=$(git ls-remote --tags --exit-code --refs $remote \
  | sed -E 's/^[[:xdigit:]]+[[:space:]]+refs\/tags\/(.+)/\1/g' | tail -n1)
        echo "TTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTT:"$recentTag
fi
echo $CHECKOUT_DIR
# Ensure that we can read the git repo location (NFS)
ls -l ${GITREPO} &> /dev/null

# Ensure that CHECKOUT_DIR exists
mkdir -p ${CHECKOUT_DIR}

# Jump into the checkout location so that we can perform the checkout/pull
 cd ${CHECKOUT_DIR}

function repoclone() {
if [ -n "$username" ]; then
        echo "Build through Jenkins job"
        echo $arg
        if [ "$arg" == "abc" ]; then
                previousABCReleaseTag=$(git ls-remote --tags https://GITHUB.XYZ.com"$arg" |grep "\."|grep -v -|grep -v {| sort -n -t. -k3 -k4)
                tagNumber=${previousABCReleaseTag##*v}
                echo "abc= v$tagNumber" >> "$arg.txt"
                echo "abc= v$tagNumber" >> durlov.txt
                sh ${BASE_DIR}/git-clone-latest-tag.sh https://github.xyz.com"$arg"
        else
                recentTag=$(git ls-remote --tags https://github.xyz.com"$arg".git |grep "\."|grep -v -|grep -v {| sort -n -t. -k3 -k4)
                tag = ${recentTag##*v}
                echo "$arg= v$tag" >> "$arg.txt"
                sh ${BASE_DIR}/git-clone-latest-tag.sh https://github.xyz.com"$arg".git
        fi
else
        echo $GITREPO
        if  [ "$arg" == "abc" ]; then
         set -x
            echo "abc= $previousABCReleaseTag" >> ${arg}.txt
            #git clone -b $ta ${GITREPO}
            echo Current working dir: ${BASE_DIR}
            git remote add ${arg} ${GITREPO}
            #sh ${BASE_DIR}/git-clone-latest-tag.sh ${GITREPO}
            # Ensure that we can read the git repo location (NFS)
            git clone ${GITREPO}
            git checkout tags/$previousABCReleaseTag
        else
        set -x
            echo "$arg= $recentTag" >> ${arg}.txt
            #git clone -b $tag --single-branch --depth 1 ${GITREPO}
            git remote add ${arg} ${GITREPO}
            #sh ${BASE_DIR}/git-clone-latest-tag.sh ${GITREPO}
            git clone ${GITREPO}
 git checkout tags/$recentTag
        fi
fi
}

if [ ! -d ${CHECKOUT_DIR}/.git ]; then
        cd ${CHECKOUT_DIR}
        # Clone the git repository
        echo "Cloning Git repository to ${CHECKOUT_DIR}"
        repoclone
else
        rm -rf $CHECKOUT_DIR
        echo $CHECKOUT_DIR
        echo "Directory deleted ,new one will be created"
        mkdir -p ${CHECKOUT_DIR}
        cd ${CHECKOUT_DIR}
        repoclone
fi

cd $CHECKOUT_DIR
echo "111111111111111111$CHECKOUT_DIR"
if [ "$arg" == "abc" ]; then
 gradle -Pproduction=true build
else
        make all

fi
```

when I run this file passing abc as the parameter like this `./abc.sh abc`,
I get the below error:

```
fatal: 'abc' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

Please help on how to fix this.

Comment: @torek in the future, please simply roll the question back to a revision with content and flag for moderator attention if it starts a rollback war (we've already got this one handled, no need to do so here).

Answer (score 2):

From the script in the question, when you run `./fetchGitRepo.sh webrtmt`, there are some problems.

```
remote=${*: -1} # Get last argument
```

Here `remote` is assigned the value `webrtmt`. And then it's used in `git ls-remote --tags --exit-code --refs $remote`. It's okay to use `git ls-remote` outside of a git repository, but a valid url is needed. Here `$remote` is `webrtmt`. It's an unknown remote and it's not a valid url either. So `git ls-remote` complains and raises the fatal error.

I think it should be `git ls-remote --tags --exit-code --refs $GITREPO` instead. The pipeline commands retrieve the expected tags.

```
ls -l ${GITREPO} &> /dev/null
```

However, then this command is odd. `${GITREPO}` is a url in ssh protocol to a remote repository, and we cannot use `ls` on it.

I'm afraid you don't pass the right parameters to the script, or the script needs modification.